# Laravel routes not working via GET while same route works via VIEW

Tags: laravel, routes

I am trying to make a route that shows the user a secondary registration form, when i use this code:

```
Route::view('RegisterFamilyMembers', 'auth.registerFamilyMembers')->name('RegisterFamilyMembers');
```

The route works fine and routes to the file, but when i try to do the same via the GET method:

```
Route::get('RegisterFamilyMembers', 'Auth\FamilyMembersController@showRegistrationForm')->name('RegisterFamilyMembers');
```

And return the view in the controller:

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return view('auth.registerFamilyMembers');
}
```

I get a RuntimeException page with no information on the problem.

does anyone know what can cause this problem?

Comment: Could you elaborate the RuntimeException you've got? Like the HTTP error code, the error message and in which file/line/instruction?

Comment: sure, (1/1) RuntimeException
Could not find resource 'views/layouts.html.php' in any resource paths.(searched: E:\XAMPP\htdocs\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Handler/../Resources) Only this doesn't happen when i use the same view via the VIEW method...

Comment: Are you on Laravel 5.8?

Comment: Laravel version 5.8.9

Comment: The issue is related to Whoops package (the error handling one) not displaying correctly, so you probably have an error in the controller binding (using Route::get) which you don't have using the Route::view method that cannot be displayed as Whoops is not working correctly. Did you run `composer install` or `composer install --no-dev` in the first place? Did you edit your `composer.json` in any way?